# ordering a collection by an association's property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

```
class Person
  belongs_to :team

class Status
  #has last_updated property

class Team
  has_many :members, :class => "Person"
```

Ok, so I have a Team class which has many People in it and each of those people has a status and each status has a last_updated property.

I'm currently rendering a partial with a collection similar to:

```
 =render :partial => "user", :collection => current_user.team.members
```

Now how do I go about sorting the collection by the last_updated property of the Status class?

Thanks in advance!

p.s.
I've just written the ruby code from memory, it's just an example, it's not meant to compile but I hope you get the idea!

Comment: Need to add `has_one :status` to your Person class?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the options mentioned you may want to use a **named_scope**:

```
class Member
  named_scope :recently_active, :joins => :status, :order => "statuses.updated_at DESC"
end

# now you can do:
current_user.team.members.recently_active
```

If you always sort members like this consider using a default_scope

```
class Member
  default_scope :joins => :status, :order => "statuses.updated_at DESC"
end

# and you can use this client code
current_user.team.members
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

1) Change the association definition to add the `order` clause.

```
class Team
  has_many :members, :class => "Person", :joins => :status, 
                   :order => "statuses.updated_at DESC"
end
current_user.team.members # ordered by updated_at
```

2) Pass the `:order` clause to the `members` method.

This method is appropriate if the `order by` column changes based on the context.

```
current_user.team.members( :joins => :status, 
                :order => "statuses.updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Assuming that `timestamp` is added to the Person table and the Status table is not used. Which is preferable unless more status information is stored.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the `members` of the `team`, you need to join `status` to pull it in. Create a named_scope (Rails 2.x) on Team that brings in members and `:joins => :status`, then `:order_by => 'statuses.last_updated'`. (also written from memory)